# delayed returning of array of collections from mongodb nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, promise

I need to retrieve a list of collections using express and mongodb module.
First, ive retrieved a list of collection names which works, I then retrieve the data of those given collections in a loop. My problem is in getColAsync():

```
getColAsync()   {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)    =>    {
        this.connectDB().then((db)  =>  {
            var allCols = [];
            let dbase = db.db(this.databaseName);
            dbase.listCollections().toArray((err, collectionNames)  =>  {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err);
                }
                else    {
                    for(let i = 0; i < collectionNames.length; i++) {
                        dbase.collection(collectionNames[i].name.toString()).find({}).toArray((err, collectionData) =>  {
                            console.log("current collection data: " + collectionData);
                            allCols[i] = collectionData;
                        })
                    }
                    console.log("done getting all data");
                    resolve(allCols);
                }
            })
        })
    })
}

connectDB() {
    if(this.dbConnection)   {
        // if connection exists
        return this.dbConnection;
    }
    else    {
        this.dbConnection = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>    {
            mongoClient.connect(this.URL, (err, db) =>  {
                if(err) {
                    console.log("DB Access: Error on mongoClient.connect.");
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err);
                }
                else    {
                    console.log("DB Access: resolved.");
                    resolve(db);
                }
            });
        });
        console.log("DB Access: db exists. Connected.");
        return this.dbConnection;
    }
}
```

In the forloop where i retrieve every collection, the console.log("done getting all data") gets called and the promise gets resolved before the forloop even begins. for example:

```
done getting all data
current collection data: something
current collection data: something2
current collection data: something3
```

Please help

Comment: Avoid [promise construction anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it/23803744#23803744).

Comment: Your main problem is a number of asynchronous operations in a `for` loop which the loop does not wait for so you call `resolve()` before any of those are done.  You can use `Promise.all()` to wait for all those to be done.  There are literally hundreds of answers here that deal with this general problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Problem

The problem in your code is this part:

```
for (let i = 0; i < collectionNames.length; i++) {
    dbase.collection(collectionNames[i].name.toString()).find({}).toArray((err, collectionData) => {
        console.log("current collection data: " + collectionData);
        allCols[i] = collectionData;
    })
}
console.log("done getting all data");
resolve(allCols);
```

You should notice that `resolve(allCols);` is called right after the `for` loop ends, but each iteration of the loop *doesn't wait for the `toArray` callback to be called*.

The line `dbase.collection(collectionNames[i].name.toString()).find({}).toArray(callback)` is asynchronous so the loop will end, you'll call `resolve(allCols);`, but the `.find({}).toArray` code won't have completed yet.

## The Solution Concept

So, basically what you did was:

1. Initialize an array of results `allCols = []`
2. Start a series of async operations
3. Return the (still empty) array of results
4. As the async operations complete, fill the now useless results array.

What you should be doing instead is:

1. Start a series of async operations
2. Wait for **all** of them to complete
3. Get the results from each one
4. Return the list of results

The key to this is the `Promise.all([/* array of promises */])` function which accepts an array of promises and returns a `Promise` itself passing downstream an array containing all the results, so what we need to obtain is something like this:

```
const dataPromises = []

for (let i = 0; i < collectionNames.length; i++) {
    dataPromises[i] = /* data fetch promise */;
}

return Promise.all(dataPromises);
```

As you can see, the last line is `return Promise.all(dataPromises);` instead of `resolve(allCols)` as in your code, so we can no longer execute this code inside of a `new Promise(func)` constructor.

Instead, we should chain `Promise`s with `.then()` like this:

```
getColAsync() {
    return this.connectDB().then((db) => {
        let dbase = db.db(this.databaseName);
        const dataPromises = []
        dbase.listCollections().toArray((err, collectionNames) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return Promise.reject(err);
            } else {
                for (let i = 0; i < collectionNames.length; i++) {
                    dataPromises[i] = new Promise((res, rej) => {
                        dbase.collection(collectionNames[i].name.toString()).find({}).toArray((err, collectionData) => {
                            console.log("current collection data: " + collectionData);
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                                reject(err);
                            } else {
                                resolve(collectionData);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
                console.log("done getting all data");
                return Promise.all(dataPromises);
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Notice now we return a `return this.connectDB().then(...)`, which in turn returns a `Promise.all(dataPromises);` this returning new `Promise`s at each step lets us keep alive the `Promise` chain, thus `getColAsync()` will itself return a `Promise` you can then handle with `.then()` and `.catch()`.

### Cleaner Code

You can clean up your code a bit as fallows:

```
getColAsync() {
    return this.connectDB().then((db) => {
        let dbase = db.db(this.databaseName);
        const dataPromises = []
        // dbase.listCollections().toArray() returns a promise itself
        return dbase.listCollections().toArray()
            .then((collectionsInfo) => {
                // collectionsInfo.map converts an array of collection info into an array of selected
                // collections
                return collectionsInfo.map((info) => {
                    return dbase.collection(info.name);
                });
            })
    }).then((collections) => {
        // collections.map converts an array of selected collections into an array of Promises
        // to get each collection data.
        return Promise.all(collections.map((collection) => {
            return collection.find({}).toArray();
        }))
    })
}
```

As you see the main changes are:

1. Using mondodb functions in their promise form
2. Using `Array.map` to easily convert an array of data into a new array

Below I also present a variant of your code using functions with callbacks and a module I'm working on.

### Promise-Mix

I'm recently working on [this npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mix?activeTab=readme) to help get a cleaner and more readable composition of Promises.

In your case I'd use the `fCombine` function to handle the first steps where you select the db and fetch the list of collection info:

```
Promise.fCombine({
    dbase: (dbURL, done) => mongoClient.connect(dbURL, done),
    collInfos: ({ dbase }, done) => getCollectionsInfo(dbase, done),
}, { dbURL: this.URL })
```

This results in a promise, passing downstream an object `{dbase: /* the db instance */, collInfos: [/* the list of collections info */]}`. Where `getCollectionNames(dbase, done)` is a function with callback pattern like this:

```
getCollectionsInfo = (db, done) => {
    let dbase = db.db(this.databaseName);
    dbase.listCollections().toArray(done);
}
```

Now you can chain the previous Promise and convert the list of collections info into selected db collections, like this:

```
Promise.fCombine({
    dbase: ({ dbURL }, done) => mongoClient.connect(dbURL, done),
    collInfos: ({ dbase }, done) => getCollectionsInfo(dbase, done),
}, { dbURL: this.URL }).then(({ dbase, collInfos }) => {
    return Promise.resolve(collInfos.map((info) => {
        return dbase.collection(info.name);
    }));
})
```

Now downstream we have a the list of selected collections from our db and we should fetch data from each one, then merge the results in an array with collection data.
In my module I have a `_mux` option which creates a `PromiseMux` which mimics the behaviour and composition patterns of a regular `Promise`, but it's actually working on several Promises at the same time. Each Promise gets in input one item from the downstream collections array, so you can write the code to fetch data from a generic collection and it will be executed for each collection in the array:

```
Promise.fCombine({
    dbase: ({ dbURL }, done) => mongoClient.connect(dbURL, done),
    collInfos: ({ dbase }, done) => getCollectionsInfo(dbase, done),
}, { dbURL: this.URL }).then(({ dbase, collInfos }) => {
    return Promise.resolve(collInfos.map((info) => {
        return dbase.collection(info.name);
    }));
})._mux((mux) => {
    return mux._fReduce([
        (collection, done) => collection.find({}).toArray(done)
    ]).deMux((allCollectionsData) => {
        return Promise.resolve(allCollectionsData);
    })
});
```

In the code above, `_fReduce` behaves like `_fCombine`, but it accepts an array of functions with callbacks instead of an object and it passes downstream only the result of the last function (not a structured object with all the results). Finally `deMux` executes a `Promise.all` on each simultaneous `Promise` of the mux, putting together their results.

Thus the whole code would look like this:

```
getCollectionsInfo = (db, done) => {
    let dbase = db.db(this.databaseName);
    dbase.listCollections().toArray(done);
}

getCollAsync = () => {
    return Promise.fCombine({
        /**
         * fCombine uses an object whose fields are functions with callback pattern to
         * build consecutive Promises. Each subsequent functions gets as input the results
         * from previous functions.
         * The second parameter of the fCombine is the initial value, which in our case is
         * the db url.
         */
        dbase: ({ dbURL }, done) => mongoClient.connect(dbURL, done), // connect to DB, return the connected dbase
        collInfos: ({ dbase }, done) => getCollectionsInfo(dbase, done), // fetch collection info from dbase, return the info objects
    }, { dbURL: this.URL }).then(({ dbase, collInfos }) => {
        return Promise.resolve(collInfos.map((info) => {
            /**
             *  we use Array.map to convert collection info into 
             *  a list of selected db collections
             */
            return dbase.collection(info.name);
        }));
    })._mux((mux) => {
        /**
         * _mux splits the list of collections returned before into a series of "simultaneous promises"
         * which you can manipulate as if they were a single Promise.
         */
        return mux._fReduce([ // this fReduce here gets as input a single collection from the retrieved list
            (collection, done) => collection.find({}).toArray(done)
        ]).deMux((allCollectionsData) => {
            // finally we can put back together all the results.
            return Promise.resolve(allCollectionsData);
        })
    });
}
```

In my module I tried to avoid most common anti-pattern thought there still is some Ghost Promise which I'll be working on.

Using the promises from mongodb this would get even cleaner:

```
getCollAsync = () => {
    return Promise.combine({
        dbase: ({ dbURL }) => { return mongoClient.connect(dbURL); },
        collInfos: ({ dbase }) => {
            return dbase.db(this.databaseName)
                .listCollections().toArray();
        },
    }, { dbURL: this.URL }).then(({ dbase, collInfos }) => {
        return Promise.resolve(collInfos.map((info) => {
            return dbase.collection(info.name);
        }));
    }).then((collections) => {
        return Promise.all(collections.map((collection) => {
            return collection.find({}).toArray();
        }))
    });
}
```